# SUM(IF(COND,EXPR,NULL)) and IF(COND, SUM(EXPR),NULL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

I'm working of generating sql request by parsing Excel-like formulas.

So for a given formula, I get this request :

```
SELECT IF(COL1='Y', SUM(EXPR),NULL)
FROM Table
```

I don't get the results I want. If I manually rewrite the request like this it works :

```
SELECT SUM(IF(COL1='Y', EXPR, NULL))
FROM Table
```

Also, the first request produces the right value if I add a GROUP BY statement, for `COL1='Y'` row :

```
SELECT IF(COL1='Y', SUM(EXPR),NULL)
FROM Table
GROUP BY COL1
```

Is there a way to keep the first syntax `IF(COND, SUM(EXPR), NULL)` and slightly edit it to make it works without a `GROUP BY` statement ?

Comment: I think you have figured out the correct logic with the second query.  That *is* the correct syntax (although I would use `case` instead of `if()`).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yep, but I wish I hadn't to touch the ANTLR grammar which produceds the line :( So why it works when I add a `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use GROUP BY since you are using SUM - otherwise SQL engine is not able to tell how do you want to summarize the column.

Alternatively you could summarize this column only:

```
SELECT SUM(EXPR)
FROM Table
WHERE COL1='Y'
```

But then you would have to run separate query for each such column, read: not recommended for performance reasons.